# Any $2\times 2$ real matrix is orthogonal similar to a diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

> Prove by direct matrix calculation that any $2\times 2$ real matrix is orthogonal similar to a diagonal matrix.

I got absent for a week in my class so i have less knowledge of it..
So all I could think about using based on what I have read is...
$P^{T}AP = D$ , $D$ a diagonal matrix
I just wanted some hints on how do I start with the proof. 
Should I generalize a 2 x 2 matrix given its properties and show that there exists D for all matrices? Thanks a lot for those who would reply.

Edit: I saw there was a theorem stating a real symmetric matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable...  so.. the columns are eigenvectors then by G-S Orthogonalization process...  I could find P and then its inverse and the diagonal... Is this structure of proof correct??

Comment: I am assuming by "any $2\times 2$ real matrix is orthogonal similar to a diagonal matrix" that you mean "any $2\times 2$ orthogonal real matrix is similar to a real matrix"?

Comment: $P^{T}.P=I$ That is orthogonal not $P^{-1}$

Comment: hmmm... I edited it I thought I made a mistake... thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: Please make titles informative and objective.

Comment: @Pedro It's my first time creating an account so spare me for my several mistakes XD... I'll be checking on these on my future posts. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Zurchi There's no need to delete the post. I've edited the title accordingly. It's OK, you'll learn and get used to the way the site works. Cheers,